# Launching uwsgi to run a Lua script to handle a form?

Tags: lua, uwsgi

Is it possible to run uwsgi as a web server with a Lua interpreter compiled in, and simply handle forms

form.html

```
<form action=script.lua method=post>
blah
</form
```

script.lua

```
-- somehow read parameters posted by form
```

The [manual](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Lua.html) assumes users want to launch uwsgi to launch a long-running Lua script:

```
./uwsgi --http --lua pippo.lua
```

Thank you.